# SharePoint Designer Data view column as parameter

Tags: sharepoint, parameters, designer, dataview

I am trying to find a way to show a column in a dataview that I may not know the field name of when creating the page, but will be selectable on the page as a parameter.  I am creating a column on a list through workflow/web services (a new person or group column which is mapped to a specific Sharepoint Group).  I am also creating an item on a different list with the same name.  The user will have an option to select select the group name in the dataview on the top half on the page, as it is included as a listbox selection.  Then, when selected, I would like to show the selected group as a column in the lower half of the page in another dataview. Is it possible to get a column name as a variable or parameter in a data view web part?

Answer (score 0):

No it would not be possible to have it as xsl column name. but you can use JavaScript to pull information

http://darrenjohnstone.net/2008/07/22/examples-for-the-sharepoint-and-office-live-javascript-api/#topic-5

Comment: I like the idea of implementing Javascript Web Services, but I don't think that helps me here.  I read the article, but don't see anything about showing a dataview column based on a variable. From the page, I will already know what column name I want to implement, I just won't know it when I am creating the page.  Please elaborate if I am missing your point.  Thanks!

Comment: basically you have to create your own html using result obtained from webservice link provides you javascript framework to access webservice and samples not solution for your problem